# unexpected output of variable in Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a Bash script with the following lines of code:

```
echo "current directory is" $PWD

echo $PWD

# put current directory into a variable for use later in script
originalDirectory=$PWD

echo "contents of original directory variable:" originalDirectory
```

And the resultant output is this:
[image]

The first 2 lines of output make sense but the 3rd one does not.  I expected it to output
`contents of original directory variable: /media/sf_code/scripts`
 but it is just printing the name of the variable.  Why doesn't it display the contents of the originalDirectory variable after the colon in that string?

Comment: ... missing `$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line should be

```
echo "contents of original directory variable:" $originalDirectory
```

Without the `$` it is text, not a variable content. So you get the text.

So it is an **expected** output ;-)

Comment: For echo the variable name wouldn't need double quoutes, but for other context it should, in case there are spaces in the directory.